# Writing alternative File Widget

Tags: 8

Okay, so I looked inside of the Managed File element and the FileWidget code and I am pretty overwhelmed.  I don't think I need anything quite so complex, but it seems like there is so much that can be done with a file widget that I don't want to do things in a way that could cause problems in the future.

I have some javascript that will upload a file to a remote server and return a url, so I want to send that url to a custom controller and save it in Drupal.  Is writing a file widget the right way to go here?

Any guidelines on where to go to find a good example of a file widget, or an explanation of how it works?

Comment: The existing file widget is probably the best example of a file widget. If you are planning on writing a custom widget then don't forget drupal 8 is object oriented and you should extend the file widget provided by core.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that at the moment, there is no example more helpful than the [Plupload](https://www.drupal.org/project/plupload) module.  It integrates with the [Plupload_widget](https://www.drupal.org/project/plupload_widget) module and extends the FileWidget from core and also has a lot of comments that I wish core would have included, explaining what the core file widget does.